# Redmine: Advanced Roadmap plugin Observe_field error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine-plugins

I have installed Advanced Roadmap plugin on redmine project.
After Installation if I try to create a new milestone, following error is thrown:

```
  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `observe_field' for # 


The form partial is as follows :

<%= error_messages_for 'milestone' %>
<div class="box">
  <p><%= f.text_field :name, :size => 60, :required => true %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :description, :size => 60 %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :effective_date, :size => 10 %><%= calendar_for('milestone_effective_date') %></p>
  <p>
    <select id="project_selector">
      <% @projects.each do |project| %>
        <option<%= (project == @project) ? " selected" : "" %> id="<%= project.id %>"><%= h(project.name) %></option>
      <% end %>
    </select>
    <% javascript_tag :defer => "defer" do %>
      function project_changed()
      {
        object = window.document.getElementById("project_selector");
        if (object)
        {
          if (object.selectedIndex != -1)
          {
            project_id = object.options[object.selectedIndex].id;
            <% @projects.each do |project| %>
              project_div = window.document.getElementById("project_<%= project.id %>_versions");
              if (project_div)
              {
                project_div.style.display = "none";
                project_div.style.visibility = "hidden";
              }
            <% end %>
            project_div = window.document.getElementById("project_" + project_id + "_versions");
            if (project_div)
            {
              project_div.style.display = "";
              project_div.style.visibility = "";
            }
          }
        }
      }
      jQuery(function($)
      {
        $(\"#project_selector\").change(project_change);
      })
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <div id="project_<%= project.id %>_versions"<%= (@project == project) ? "" : "style=\"display: none; visibility: hidden;\"" %>>
    <table class="list">
    <thead>
      <th><%= l(:field_version) %></th>
      <th><%= l(:field_effective_date) %></th>
      <th><%= l(:field_description) %></th>
      <th><%= l(:label_milestone_plural) %></th>
    </thead>
    <% project.versions.sort.each do |version| %>
      <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") %>">
        <td>
          <%= check_box_tag "versions[]", version.id, @milestone.versions?(version) %>
          <%= link_to(h(version.name), :controller => :versions, :action => :show, :id => version) %>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><%= version.effective_date %></td>
        <td><%= version.description %></td>
        <td align="center"><%= version.milestones.collect {|m| link_to(h(m.name), :controller => :milestones, :action => :show, :id => m.id) }.join(", ").html_safe %></td>
      <tr>
    <% end %>
   </table>
  </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>
```

How should we change he observe field issue as it has been deprecated.Any help will be appreciated.

I am using

- `ruby 1.9.3` -version
- `rails 3.2.13` version
- `redmine 2.x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little search i found the solution for the above issue.

Obviously observe_field method has been deprecated in rails 3.

So in order to solve this issue, we need to just remove the observe_field helper method and add a javascript code inside javascript_tag of the view template as follows:

```
<% javascript_tag :defer => "defer" do %>
  function project_changed()
  {
    object = window.document.getElementById("project_selector");
    if (object)
    {
      if (object.selectedIndex != -1)
      {
        project_id = object.options[object.selectedIndex].id;
        <% @projects.each do |project| %>
          project_div = window.document.getElementById("project_<%= project.id %>_versions");
          if (project_div)
          {
            project_div.style.display = "none";
            project_div.style.visibility = "hidden";
          }
        <% end %>
        project_div = window.document.getElementById("project_" + project_id + "_versions");
        if (project_div)
        {
          project_div.style.display = "";
          project_div.style.visibility = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  jQuery(function($)
  {
    $(\"#project_selector\").change(project_change);
  })
<% end %>
```

what exactly is done is just we removed helper method and added a small jquery code.

```
  jQuery(function($)
  {
    $(\"#project_selector\").change(project_change);
  })
```